# Node.js on MAC: Access a Node.js web server from another computer

Tags: node.js

I built a Node.js web server on my computer, using the so-well-known-http-web-server-example of Node.js:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('It works');
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

This works (as expected) on the computer that runs the server.

I would like to access the server from another computer, in the same LAN. Using `ifconfig` on the terminal of the computer that runs the server (Apple MacOSX), I get: `192.168.0.6`.

So, in my other computer, I opened my browser and connected to `http://192.168.0.6:3000`, but I get:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.0.6:3000
```

My final aim, is to be able to connect to the server using my smartphone.

Any help would be welcome. Don't hesitate to ask for more details if necessary.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is only local interface. Try to start listening all interfaces:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('It works');
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot Vadim, it works (even in my smartphone). Can you give more details (if possible)?

Comment: Your machine have several network interfaces. You can see it all by executing `ifconfig` command. By setting `127.0.0.1` you binding your node.js server to loopback interface only. This interface acessible only from machine where it running. `0.0.0.0` is alias to all available interfaces. Also you can bind your server to another selected interface like a `192.168.0.6` but it should not be acessible by `http://127.0.0.1:3000` in this case.

Comment: Thank you Vadim. Now I undersand more how it works. Indeed, when I bind the server to `192.168.0.6`, it works when accessing this address, but not the `localhost`. Thanks again.

Comment: I also have a connection in node.js in my computer, 192.168.1.101. I bind to this address in the server, but still can't access my HTML page from another computer. Any help?